# How to list in jsp Collection < Object>

Tags: spring-mvc, collections

I have @oneToMany relationship  Member -> Phone .

**@entity ( Member )**

```
private Collection<Phone> phonesById;
```

and i try to list in table to member's phones.

```
<c:forEach items="${Members}" var="Member">
                <tr>
                    <td> ${Member.tcNo} </td>
                    <td> ${Member.name} ${Member.surname}</td>
                    <td> ${Member.mail} </td>
                    <td> ${Member.job} </td>
                    <td>
                        <table class="table table- table-hover table-advance">
                            <thead>
                              <c:forEach items="${Member.phonesById}" var="phone">
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                      ${phone.phone}
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </c:forEach>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/member_update/${Member.id}"><button type="button" class="btn green-jungle">Güncelle</button></a>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/member_delete/${Member.id}"><button type="button" class="btn red">Sil</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

error : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.cm.entity.Member.phonesById, could not initialize proxy - no Session

How can i display in table of jsp page ?

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: ok. im editting right now.

Comment: Also, you need to ask a question.

Comment: i already asked in title ." how to list "